# Comparison of classifier confusion matrices

Tags: python, logistic-regression, k-nn, confusion-matrix, lda-classifier

I tried implementing Logistic regression, Linear Discriminant Analysis and KNN for the [smarket dataset](https://rdrr.io/cran/ISLR/man/Smarket.html) provided in "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" in python.

Logistic Regression and LDA was pretty straight forward in terms of implementation. Here are the confusion matrices on a test dataset.

[image]
[image]

Both of them are pretty similar with almost same accuracy. But I tried finding a K for KNN by plotting the loss vs K graph:

[image]

and chose a K around 125 to get this confusion matrix (same test dataset)

[image]

Although the KNN gave a higher accuracy of around 0.61, the confusion matrix is very different from logistic and LDA matrices with a much higher true negative and a low true positive. I cant really understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I computed loss for KNN Classifier (using Sklearn). Could not use MSE since the Y values are qualitative.

```
k_set = np.linspace(1,200, dtype=int)
knn_dict = {}

for k in k_set:
    model = KNeighborsClassifier(k)
    model.fit(train_X, train_Y)
    y_pred = model.predict(test_X)
    loss = 1 - metrics.accuracy_score(test_Y, y_pred)
    knn_dict[k] = loss

model = KNeighborsClassifier(K)
model.fit(train_X, train_Y)
knn_y_pred = model.predict(test_X)

knn_cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(test_Y, knn_y_pred)
```

Very new to data science. I hope I have provided enough background/context. Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

- I don't know this dataset but it seems to be a difficult one to classify since the performance is not much better than a random baseline (the random baseline in binary classification gives 50% accuracy, since it guesses right half the time).
- If I'm not mistaken the majority class (class 1) has 141 instances out of 252, i.e. 56% (btw the numbers are not easily readable in the matrices). This means that a classifier which automatically assigns class 1 would reach 56% accuracy. This is called the majority baseline, this is usually the minimal performance one wants to reach with a binary classifier. The LR and LDA classifiers are worse than this, so practically they don't really work.
- The k-NN classifier appears to give better results indeed, and importantly above 56% so it actually "learns" something useful.
- It's a bit strange that the first 2 classifers predict class 0 more often than class 1. It looks as if the training set and test set don't have the same distribution.
- the k-NN classifier correcly predicts class 1 more often, and that's why it works better. k-NN is also much less sensitive to the data distribution: in case it differs between training and test set, this could explain the difference with the first 2 classifiers.
- However it's rarely meaningful for the $k$ in $k$-NN to be this high (125). Normally it should be a low value, like one digit only. I'm not sure what this means in this case.
- Suggestion: you could try some more robust classifiers like decision trees (or random forests) or SVM.